# How to chunk and send to server video files in android

Tags: android, video

Hi i am uploading big video files to server using Volley Multi-part Api but it's taking so  much time for uploading

I decided to **chunk** my video files before send to server but i really **ignore** about how to chunk videos files

can some one help me please

### code:-

```
finalFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
SendFileToserver(finalFile)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload big videos files to server quickly in androd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43672041/how-to-upload-big-videos-files-to-server-quickly-in-androd)